# Jaxb configuration at run time

Tags: jaxb

I have a business case where I will have about 10 different pojo's available to map to 10 different incoming xml files ie.(location, product, order, item ....) I was wondering if they is a way in JAXB to configure that. May be a configuration file to map the xml file to the right class. therefore I will not have to put logic in my code to determine the right class

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the crude example I've shown below to use a file to map classes to XML files. You'll have to adapt it to match what your specific needs are.

I created some very simple classes to hold some primitive data types to illustrate the use:

**ClassOne:**

```
package so27409179;

@XmlRootElement(name="ClassOne")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassOne {
    @XmlElement(name="Field")
    String field;

    public ClassOne() {

    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassOne\n" + "\tField = " + getField();
    }
}
```

**ClassTwo:**

```
package so27409179;

@XmlRootElement(name="ClassTwo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassTwo {
    @XmlElement(name="Field1")
    String field1;
    @XmlElement(name="Field2")
    int field2;
    @XmlElement(name="Field3")
    double field3;

    public ClassTwo() {

    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public int getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(int field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public double getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public void setField3(double field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassTwo\n" +
                "\tField1 = " + getField1() +
                "\n\tField2 = " + getField2() +
                "\n\tField3 = " + getField3();
    }
}
```

**ClassThree:**

```
package so27409179;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ClassThree")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassThree {
    @XmlElement(name="Field1")
    String field1;
    @XmlElement(name="Field2")
    String field2;

    public ClassThree() {

    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassThree\n" +
                "\tField1 = " + getField1() +
                "\n\tField2 = " + getField2();
    }
}
```

Then I created a simple mapping file (comma delimited) that maps file names to class names. I called this file `mappings.txt`:

```
XmlFile1.xml,so27409179.ClassOne
XmlFile2.xml,so27409179.ClassTwo
XmlFile3.xml,so27409179.ClassThree
```

Then I created some dummy XML files to correspond to the mappings:

**XmlFile1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ClassOne>
    <Field>Some Class 1 Field Value</Field>
</ClassOne>
```

**XmlFile2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ClassTwo>
    <Field1>Some Class 2 Field Value</Field1>
    <Field2>100</Field2>
    <Field3>12.34</Field3>
</ClassTwo>
```

**XmlFile3.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ClassThree>
    <Field1>Some Class 3 Field Value</Field1>
    <Field2>Another Class 3 Field Value</Field2>
</ClassThree>
```

Then I created a test class that reads this file and puts the file name and the class object corresponding to the class name into a `Map` that you can choose to use for whatever you want, as well as unmarshal the data and print out the information it read

```
public class TestClassMapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Class> classMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();

        try {
            // reader for reading mapping file
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("mappings.txt"));

            String line;
            // read each line in the file
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                // split the data
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                String fileName = parts[0]; // file name
                Class clazz = Class.forName(parts[1]); // class object
                classMap.put(fileName, clazz);  // you might want to do something with this later...

                // unmarshal the data
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
                Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
                // generic object
                Object o = u.unmarshal(new File(fileName));
                // print out the data received
                System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

The following output is observed:

```
ClassOne
    Field = Some Class 1 Field Value
ClassTwo
    Field1 = Some Class 2 Field Value
    Field2 = 100
    Field3 = 12.34
ClassThree
    Field1 = Some Class 3 Field Value
    Field2 = Another Class 3 Field Value
```

Good luck, hope this helps.